# Add props to component only if it has associate properties being passed down

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Select component thats needs an icon appended as input adornment , only if it is being passed down from parent.

```
<Select
        className={classes.select}
        native
        input={<FilledInput 
            { ...icon && {
                startAdornment={
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <AccountCircle />
                </InputAdornment>
            }}}
            className={classes.inputContainer} 
            name={this.props.label} 
            id={this.props.id} />}
        >
```

It just keeps giving unexpected token error. What is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<Select
    className={classes.select}
    native
    input={
        <FilledInput 
            {...icon ? {
                startAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                    <AccountCircle />
                </InputAdornment>
                )
            } : {}}
            className={classes.inputContainer} 
            name={this.props.label} 
            id={this.props.id}
        />
    }
>
```